# Add User in wordpress without username

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have made a registration form which have only two fields email and password .Now i want to add user to Wordpress database but `wp_create_user()` require username too.Then i tried using another function as `$status=wp_insert_user($userdata);` where $userdata is an array containing elements as

```
$userdata = array(
                'user_pass'   =>  $pswrd,
                'user_email'=> $email
            );
```

but user is not added in database. Is their any other function through which i can add user with above two fields only.

Comment: why don't you give an empty name with wp_create_user?

Comment: Yeah it worked.Thnxx Christian

Comment: @Er.NavedAli if the answer helpful try to give up vote

Comment: @Firefog at that time i dont have required reputation points .Now i have it i up-voted your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one** [example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)

```
$userdata = array(
                    'user_login'  =>  '',
                    'user_pass'   =>  $pswrd,
                    'user_email'=> $email
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to ask the user for a specific login name, you could use their e-mail:

```
if ( !username_exists( $email ) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $email, $pswrd, $email );

    if ( !is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        // created succesfully

    }
} else {
    // Username already exists

}
```

Comment: This works, but I had to edit the database to drop user_login and user_nicename as indexes... and after adding users, I edited the database to change those columns to the user names.  WTF wordpress!